# Is there any better documentation on overiding the django ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

I want to use the django Admin side as my main app for the website.
I want to override the methods avaiable in ModelAdmin like here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

is there any better tutorial avaiable for those methods with examples

Comment: Better documentation? probably not no. That documentation is very good and contains lots of examples. Other examples and tutorials? I can see 4 tutorials on the first page of google. Why don't you post some code and explain what it is your trying to do. Which methods are you trying to override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and most accurate source of information about ModalAdmin is [source code of BaseModelAdmin and ModelAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.3/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L60).